# Things board Auto refresh timseries line chart

Tags: thingsboard

I'm using the latest thingsboard docker image.
I have a dashboard with a timeseries line chart. The time window of the timeseries line chart widget is set to an historical time range.

Does someone know how to have this widget that auto refresh when things board receive a new telemetry ?
I think that the widget does not refresh automatically because the time window is set to an historical time range. But when the time window is set to "real time", I can't set a fixed custom time range in the past as example, from 08/09/2023 to 09/09/2023.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are somehow contradictory. On the one hand, the time window should be fixed, but it should also be able to adapt to changes in value.

This is not supported by ThingsBoard. Either you opt for "Realtime" or "Historical" timerange.

I would recommend working with "Realtime" and Interval. You can also show the time window setting to the user so that they can change historical time ranges themselves if required.